# calculadora javascript sin usar eval();

Tags: javascript

```
var memoria = document.getElementById('pantalla').value;
var memoria2 = document.getElementById('pantalla').value;
//almaceno en variable el valor del campo id="pantalla", en esta caso es un input tipo text.
```

Ahora debo crear función que:

- Borre campo `input` tipo `text` con `id="pantalla"`, pero conserve el valor de la variable memoria.
- Debo volver a escribir otro valor en el campo `input` tipo `text` con `id="pantalla"` y sumarlo a la variable memoria.

He tratado de hacer esto pero no funciona.
¿Alguien tiene alguna idea mejor de como lo podría hacer?

```
function sumar(){
  document.getElementById('pantalla').value = ""; //Esto borra el campo.
   document.getElementById('pantalla').value = "memoria2";
   var suma = (memoria + memoria2)
   document.calcu.visor.value = suma;
}
```

Comment: Hola, parece que hiciste la misma pregunta anteriormente? http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29346/como-puedo-sumar-2-valores-del-mismo-campo-input-borrando-el-valor-anterior

Comment: Deberías crear un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para que podamos ver qué es lo que falla y cómo. Sólo con lo que compartes no queda muy claro lo que intentas hacer o qué tiene que ver el `eval()` en todo esto.

Answer (score 1):

**Prueba usando [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)**

```js
(function() {
  var pantalla = document.getElementById('pantalla'),
    valor = document.getElementById('valor'),
    sumar = document.getElementById('sumar'),
    borrar = document.getElementById('borrar'),
    memoria = 0;
  
  sumar.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var numero = parseFloat(valor.value, 10) || 0;
    
    memoria += numero;
    pantalla.value = memoria;
    valor.value = '';
  });
  borrar.addEventListener('click', function() {
    memoria = 0;
    pantalla.value = memoria;
  });
})();
```

```html
Pantalla: <input type="text" id="pantalla" readonly /><br />
Valor: <input type="text" id="valor" /><br />
<input type="button" id="sumar" value="Sumar" /><br />
<input type="button" id="borrar" value="Borrar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Añade la variable dentro de la función y otra variable que controle las veces que se envió el input

```js
var num = 0
function sumar(){
  if(num == 0){
    var memoria = document.getElementById('pantalla').value
    document.getElementById('pantalla').value = ""
    num++
  }
  else if(num == 1){
    var memoria2 = document.getElemtById('pantall').value
    document.getElementById('pantalla').value = ""
  }
  else{
    var suma = memoria + momoria2
    document.calcu.visor.value = suma
  }
}
```

Comment: Parece una buena solucion, lo probaré y si funciona te comento algo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si lo implemento y funciona te digo algo y te valoro positivamente.